# iphone keyboard keydown/keyup events?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, keyboard-events, uikeyboard

I am wondering why I am not able to find any help regarding the keyboard keyup/keydown events, I actually want to detect which key is been pressed by the user via keyboard on iphone while inputting the text in the UITextField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this delegate method to get the character that's being entered into a UITextField:

`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;`

For example:

```
if ([string isEqualToString:@"z"]){
    // z is being typed.
}
```

Just make sure you've said your UITextField's delegate to the class file where you implement this.

Comment: Thanks for the help tom :) .... but i ve used a bit different method, i called the desired function via notification centre and then i check the UITextFiled Variable that i defined in the view controller interface.

Comment: That's a totally different thing from the one he asked. For example, you won't get an event if the backspace is pressed within an empty textField.